# Взять значение из соседней ячейки Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Есть исходная таблица:

[image: Есть исходная таблица Excel]

1)В столбце "В" всегда находятся только даты. Даты необходимо перенести на новый лист в столбец "А" без пробелов.
2)Необходимо пройти по столбцу "С" И если в нём встречается символ "х", то необходимо взять значение из соседнего столбца "D" и перенести на другой лист в столбец " B".  В столбце "D" Могут встречаться значения не только рядом со значением "X".

Таблица которая должна получиться:

[image: таблица которая должна получиться]

Comment: Отлично всё это, конечно... а вопрос-то какой?

Comment: Откорректировал вопрос. Если кратко то из первой таблицы нужно получить вторую.

Comment: Ну делайте, мы-то тут при чём? вот когда будут вполне конкретные вопросы по реализации какого-то определённого момента - приходите да спрашивайте. А ежели хотите "я ни фига не знаю и делать не хочу, сделайте за меня" - так это на фриланс...